# data QueryParam (sym :: Symbol) a -- what does that mean?

Tags: haskell

I've seen this in Haskell code:

```
data QueryParam (sym :: Symbol) a
```

What does this mean? Where is a constructor? Is it valid code without any extension?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is a data declaration without a constructor -- declarations like this indicate that the type `QueryParam` has a *kind* of type `Symbol`

It is used with information that works at a type level -- it's comparable to  `data QueryParam a = QueryParam Symbol a` but at the type level instead of the value level.

Comment: You need KindSignatures and perhaps EmptyDataDecls.

Comment: trivia: EmptyDataDecls was added in Haskell 2010 so you don't need to turn it on, usually